# How to make a friend of a partially specialized template class to another partially specialized template class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, template-specialization

I require a template specialised class to make `friend` with another template specialised class.

Example:

```
template <class A, class B>
class X { };

template <class A, class B>
class Y { };
```

Now I want to have *only* some specific specialisations of these template classes to be friends:

I tried

```
template <class A>
class X <A, bool> { };

template <class A>
class Y <A, bool>
{
    // X<A, bool> shall be friend!
    template<class _C> using X_partial = X<_C,bool>;
    template<class _D> friend class X_partial;

};
```

and this,

```
template <class A>
class X <A, bool> { };

template <class A>
class Y <A, bool>
{
    // X<A, bool> shall be friend!
    template<class C> friend class X<class C,bool> 

};
```

But both gives the  error .

The syntax can support C++(03), C++11 or C++14.

Comment: classs are template<class A,bool> class X{};

Comment: Second Class is template <class A,bool> class y{     }; And I want how to make class y a friend of class X.

Comment: Please have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Add the code of what you have tried so far, and add it in the question, not as comment.

Comment: Now is this right: `X<B, bool>` shall be friend for any arbitrary B?

Comment: @Aconagua Yes, X<A,bool> shall be friend for any arbitrary C.

Comment: @AmanGupta I sense there is XY problem to the question. Maybe friendship is not the answer at all. To the original intent of the question, the answer is then no, workarounds could well be "hacky". If the original problem being solved is expanded on (maybe as a new question that references this question), there may be alternatives that are more workable.

Answer (score 1):

The friend declaration cannot declare a partial specialization. See [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.friend#7).

> Friend declarations shall not declare partial specializations. [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T> class A { };
> class X {
>   template<class T> friend class A<T*>;         // error
> };
> ```
>
> — end example ]

However, if the "initial" types for `A` are the same, then to provide friendship to the correct specialization, it is as follows;

```
template <class A, class B>
class Y { };

template <class A, class B>
class X {
public:
    // fails to compile when instantiated
    //X() { Y<A, bool> y; y.i = 42; }
};

template <class A>
class Y <A, bool>
{
    // partial specialisation provided friendship
    friend class X<A, bool>;
    int i = 0;
};

template <class A>
class X <A, bool> {
public:
    X() { Y<A, bool> y; y.i = 42; }
};

int main()
{
    X<int, bool> x1;
    // fails to compile.
    X<int, int> x2;
}
```

[Sample online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fa656ff698cac06).

Comment: why you make a object of class Y<A,bool> in constructor of class X<A,bool>

Comment: @AmanGupta What do you mean by "not working"? It compiles fine unless you uncomment the constructor in the non-specialised X - which then *must* fail as X<int, int> is *not* a friend of Y<A, bool>, which is the desired behaviour...

Comment: @Niall With the template-typedef added in the question, I think the question is how to do `template <class A> class Y <A, bool> { template <class B> friend class X<B, bool>; };` - possible szenario: `class C { typedef double type; }; X<A, bool>::X() { Y<typename A::type, bool> y; y.i = 42; }; X<C, bool> x;`, which would try to access private part of `Y<double, bool>` within `X<C, bool>` without being friend...

Comment: @Aconcagua Comment the object  of Y<A,bool> in constructor X<A,bool> and make both the object in main and then try to access the private member of friend class. Its not working.

Comment: @Aconcagua. From what I think you are saying, friend declarations cannot declare partial specializations. See http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.friend#7

Comment: @Niall And that's the point of the question... So answer clearly is: "Not possible!"...

Comment: @Niall Yes, you are correct in previous comment, that why find another way to solve the problem.

Comment: @Aconcagua. I sense there is XY problem to the question. Maybe friendship is not the answer at all. To the original intent of the question, the answer is then no, workarounds could well be "hacky". If the original problem being solved is expanded on, there may be alternatives that are more workable.

Answer (score 0):

Where is a problem in that? What have you tried before asking this question?

```
// Templated class X
template <class A, bool>
class X {

};

// Templated class Y
template <class A, bool>
class Y {
    // Any specialized A is a friend of any specialized B
    template <class B, bool> friend class X;
};
```

**Edit:** Update with classes you provided in comment on your question.

Comment: class1 is  template<class A> class X<A,bool>{}; Class2 is template <class A> class y<A,bool>{ };

Comment: The syntax you wrote is invalid. You can declare class with one template parameter and specialize it with 2 parameters.

Comment: @AmanGupta These are not correct specialisations, must be `template <class A> class X<A, true|false> {};` (one of true/false!).

Comment: If the classes should look like you specified in comment under your question, there is a updated solution. If this has solved your porblem consider upvoting and marking it. Thanks

Comment: @MarošBeťko I think he does not want to have *all* specialisations being friends, but only very specific ones. Unfortunately, question is not very clear about, and we have to be guessing from code in comments...

Comment: @ Maroš Beťko class are the specilized class ... main syntex is template<class A,class B> class X{}; template <class A> class X<A,bool>

Comment: Second class is template<class A,class B> class Y{}; template<A> class Y<A,bool> {};

Comment: @AmanGupta Update you question to clearly state what you want please. Also add some code that you are currently working with.

Comment: @AmanGupta You are aware that you change your template classes with every new comment? Be so kind and add *all* the code you posted so far to the **question** itself to make your actual intentions clear. Offer of mine: I'll do it for you so that you can see how a good question might look like. If I guessed your issue correctly, fine, otherwise fix it appropriately...

Comment: @MarošBeťko @ Aconcagua  I want to make template<A> class Y<A,bool> friend of template<class A> class X<A,bool> which are template specilized classs of template <class A,class B> class Y{}; and template<class A,class B> class X{};